# is a compound literal not a literal?

Tags: c

From C in a Nutshell:

> **Chapter 3 Literals**
>
> In C source code, **a literal** is a token that denotes **a fixed value**, which may be an integer,  a  floating-point  number,  a  character,  or  a  string.  A  literal’s  type  is  determined by its value and its notation.
>
> The literals discussed here are different from compound literals, which were introduced in the C99 standard.
> **Compound literals** are ordinary **modifiable** objects, similar to variables.  For a full description of compound literals and the special operator
> used to create them, see Chapter 5.

So a literal has a fixed value, i.e. its value can't be modified, while a compound literal has modifiable values.

According to that, which one is correct:

- a compound literal is not a literal, or
- the definition of literal should be extended to include a compound literal which becomes the only one exception  to the fixed-value rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C11 standard never defines "literal" on its own. It only speaks of "string literal" and "compound literal" individually.

Tokens such as `0`, `0.0`, the `A` in `enum { A }`, and `'\0'` are called "constants" collectively, and "integer constants", "floating-point constants", "enumeration constants", and "character constants" respectively.